# Image stretching and dominant color picking like iTunes does

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can i achieve what iTunes does?
The album art gets stretched and blurred, also it picks colors from the image and use those colors for the text.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxw21.png)

For the blur i know how to do it.
But how i can stretch the image while maintain the aspect ratio?
There isn't an option in `NSImageView` for this.. only stretch on both axis.

The question are 2:

1. **How to stretch an image to it's container while maintaining aspect ratio?**
2. **How to pick dominant colors in a image?**

To explain better the image stretching that i want, here is an example, showing how the image have to scale, based on width or height of the container.

[image]

Comment: The title of your topic says Custom NSView with blurred image like iTunes does suggesting as if you needed to know how to blur an image.  You then say you know how to do it.  So what's your point?  Why don't make it clear with the title?

Comment: You might want to look at this tutorial on [dominant color detection](http://aishack.in/tutorials/dominant-color/)

Answer (score 1):

The guys at Panic did a nice writeup on how to choose the colours (with a sample app)

https://github.com/panicinc/ColorArt

NSImageValue has a setImageScaling:

```
NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown, // Scale image to maximum possible dimensions while (1) staying within destination area (2) preserving aspect ratio
```

which seems to fit what you're saying.

Comment: Thanks for the link, exactly what i needed.
For the image, it's not exactly what i want.
I want the image to always cover the container, even if exceed the container. If i have an image of 50x50 and the container is 50x30, the image must stay at 50x50 filling the container, even if the height of the container is less than the height of the image.